# How to exclude -1 sentinel value when finding minimum element in an array, java

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the minimum element in an array of size 25 elements are read by user and should stop when the user enters -1

```
import java.util.*;
public class LabSheet4{
public static void main (String[] args){
Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);

double scores[] = new double[25];
int minIndex=0, i =0, sentinel=0;


do{
scores[i] = read.nextDouble();
if(scores[i]==-1)
sentinel=-1;
i++;}while(sentinel!=-1);

for(int k=0;k<scores.length;k++)
if(scores[minIndex] > scores[k] && scores[minIndex]>0)
minIndex = k;
lowestScore = scores[minIndex];}}
```

How do I exclude -1?

Answer (score 0):

**Do not store -1 in `scores` at all.**
That way you won't have to exclude it later.

**Most importantly,
it's not a functional value like the other values you store,
but a symbol with a special technical meaning in the way you process input.**
As such, it doesn't belong in the `scores` array.

Change your loop that reads the user input,
so as to not store -1.
Check the input before you store it,
and break out of the loop if it is -1:

```
while (true) {
    double input = read.nextDouble();
    if (input == -1) {
        break;
    }
    scores[i++] = input;
}
```

Btw, what will happen if the user enters 26 values that are not -1?
The program will crash, because `scores` can only store 25 values.
So you need further some improvements to prevent that from happening.
For example you could use a `for` loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    double input = read.nextDouble();
    if (input == -1) {
        break;
    }
    scores[i] = input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to not put the value in the list until *after* you know it isn't the sentinel.

Another would be to not increment the counter when you find you have added the sentinel.  Note that this means you need a slightly bigger array.

Answer (score 0):

One way is not to store it in the first place but another fix would be to ignore it when running on the array like this.

```
   for(int k=0;k<scores.length;k++)
        if(scores[minIndex] > scores[k] && scores[minIndex]>0 && scores[k] !=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One common idiom for this class of problems, is to use a `while` loop with an assignment and test. Something like,

```
double scores[] = new double[25];
int i = 0;
double score;
while ((score = read.nextDouble()) != -1) {
    scores[i] = score;
    i++;
}
```

Then you could start at `0` and iterate from `1` to `i` (because `0` is your initial value and `i` is the count of elements). Like,

```
int minIndex = 0;
for (int k = 1; k < i; k++) {
    if (scores[minIndex] > scores[k]) {
        minIndex = k;
    }
}
double lowestScore = scores[minIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if(scores[i]==-1)
sentinel=-1;
```

use

```
if (scores[i]==-1 && i > 0) {
    sentinel=-1;
    scores[i] = scores[minIndex];
    }
```

so you replace `-1` with (so far) the lowest value - which is OK, isn't it?.